# How to create porous material

Tags: texturing, materials

Porous material
I tried to model a porous material which contain empty spheres or complex shapes, modeling it into a cube.

[image]
<sub>(source: [scielo.br](http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/mr/2011nahead/AOP_0835-11fig11.jpg))</sub>

I found this video as an example, but the procedure was made by Cinema 4D with an add plugin.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcRlTK0TUBg
Is there a technique to use procedural textures and volumetric effects to these porous texture, or if there's a script to do!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use 3d dimensional procedural textures for volumetric rendering:
[image]

With a node setup like:

[image]

The scale of the voronoi texture controls the size of the bubbles. You could also try noise or musgrave texture with different settings.

For more details I reduced the step size in the volumnetric render settings:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]
1-  Using a particle system and a sphere mesh as the object fill
a box the more variety in sizes the better, the box will need to be larger than your final "block"

2-  Convert the particle spheres to real geometry and join them together into one mesh.

follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gM8yEMFMjg

Then using modifiers ,

3-  Remesh using voxels.

4-  Decimate to break up spherical obvious shape.

5-  Boolean intersection the sphere mass with a box with a box with actual dimensions you want .

6-  An other voxel remesh (finer resolution)to eliminate boolean artefacts.

[image]

Comment: this reads like a link-only answer.

Answer (score -1):

As to make volumetric porousity on volume level for your bony object ,I found a useful blog with beautiful open source downloadable plugin AtomBlend, developed in Sydney by Vavara Efremova under the supervision of Anna Ceguerra, Simon Ringer and Peter Felfer. It works for Nano particles material research . so can handle enormous number of vertices for visualisation , render and analysis .You can load your object vertics data and make Atomic view and switch halo material (circles as atoms) to Vertex duplication (spheres as atoms) by switching On Vertex Duplication in the object tab.

http://www.peterfelfer.org/?p=214
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Please do not go around just copy pasting your "answer" to any question that sounds like it will fit. As it is you have given *very* little information on how to use this addon. The screen shots you lifted from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rExxslyKpAQ) do not really help (aside from making it look less like a link only answer.)

Comment: you are right , but some answers are applicable for more than one question , what to do for?

Comment: The linked site does not exist (anymore?), the site isn't even registered to anyone anymore.