# Transform a solid to a specific porous structure

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a 3D stl file, which is solid. I would like to be able to create a porous structure of 300 nanometers size pores.
Any help?

Comment: See related for creating porous material - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/how-to-create-porous-material. Their size won't be that accurate, of course and I'm not sure if there's a automate way to create them of the same size other than scripting.

Comment: Are you trying to *model* the pores, or *texture* the pores?